# How to get all items in a RepeaterControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater which gets data bound by a paged data source, which displays 25 items in the repeater at a time.

Each row in the repeater has a check box in it...

What I am trying to do is on a button click check all the checkboxes in the repeater...and then in code loop through the controls in the repeaterand get all the rows that are checked.

But the problem I am having is the fact that it only gets the 25 checkboxes on the current page (which was limited by the PagedDataSource), but I need to get ALL rows.

Please assist.

Here is the loop i was using:

```
int count = 0;
            foreach (Control item in repeater.Controls)
            {
                foreach (Control innerControl in item.Controls)
                {
                    if (innerControl.ID == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (innerControl.ID == "chk")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Rather than checking the boxes, have you considered changing the value in the underlying data source, and then re-binding the repeater to reflect the changes to the data?  It's clean, and bypasses the 25 item limit wihtough disabling paging.

Comment: its a web form...asp.net

Comment: You cant check check boxes that does not exist. Go with @DavidStratton suggestion.

Comment: Use the suggestion above, go back to the Database, then rebind the Repeater based on the Button click.  You'll call a different SP but the underyling code to bind will then be near identical.

Comment: @David Stratton thanks, I did that